# Calculating individual probabilities for an unknown distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I encountered the following problem:

According to the Internal Revenue Service, the average length of time for an individual to complete (keep records for, learn, prepare, copy, assemble, and send) IRS Form 1040 is 10.53 hours (without any attached schedules). The distribution is unknown. Let us assume that the standard deviation is two hours. Suppose we randomly sample 36 taxpayers.

Would you be surprised if one taxpayer finished his or her Form 1040 in more than 12 hours? In a complete sentence, explain why.

How can we solve this problem, as it is explicitly stated that the distribution is unknown? In that case we would always have to use the central limit theorem to determine the probability that the *mean* is over 12 hours, but not that an individual takes over 12 hours, no?

The solution given there is:

"No. I would not be totally surprised because the probability is 0.2312".

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to approach this problem, as I always thought one need to know the distribution when you try to calculate the individual probabilities and not sums or means.

The problem is Question 7.2.3 from:

https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_Statistics/Book%3A_Introductory_Statistics_(OpenStax)/07%3A_The_Central_Limit_Theorem/7.E%3A_The_Central_Limit_Theorem_(Exercises)

Comment: It may be that the point of the exercise is to know that the CLT does *not* apply in this case, so there is nothing much you can say about the probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps better to say something like

> "No. I would not be totally surprised because if I assumed a normal distribution and a standard deviation of $2$ then the probability an individual taking more than $12$ hours or higher would be $0.2312$. Those assumptions are likely to be wrong, but are enough to judge whether I would be surprised by at least one individual taking over $12$ hours."

In fact, with those assumptions, I would be surprised that only one of the $36$ took more than $12$ hours.